# Que es el protocolo buffer en Python?

Tags: python

-Hoy empece a ver el tema de los objetos binarios en Python `(bytes / bytearrays)` y entiendo la idea perfectamente, son basicamente objetos empleados para representar informacion a traves de notacion hexadecimal, sin embargo, me surgieron varias dudas (dos especificamente). La primera es la siguiente: que es el *protocolo buffer*??. Trate de ver la documentacion, sin embargo no se me hace muy entendible ...

```
"Si bien cada uno de estos tipos tiene su propia semántica (bytes / bytearrays), 
comparten la característica común de estar respaldados por un búfer de memoria 
posiblemente grande. Es deseable, en algunas situaciones, acceder a ese búfer 
directamente y sin copia intermedia."
```

-Da a entender que usualmente se crean copias entre los datos que se perciben en el programa y el buffer (o al menos es esto lo que entendi). Segun creia el buffer es basicamente una memoria de almacenamiento temporal en donde se almacenan datos para que los procesos no se queden sin los mismos, en este caso, el buffer seria el `cli` de la terminal. Por lo visto, el concepto de buffer que concibo no es el correcto ...

**Modificacion:** he ahondado un poco mas en el tema, la vista se me aclaro un poco cuando vi los `memoryview`. Por lo visto, el *protocolo buffer* es un modo de acceder y trabajar directamente sobre objetos sin la necesidad de realizar una copia (como suele ocurrir con por ejemplo las cadenas de texto), a lo cual se le denomina el *nivel C* (ciertamente en `C` se trabaja directamente sobre los datos y jamas se crean copias a menos que se realize explicitamente), el punto esta en que este *protocolo buffer* solo es soportado por `bytes / bytearrays`. Con lo cual, la pregunta se modifica : es esto cierto? mi concepcion de buffer es la correcta?

Comment: Comento para corregir otro error de interpretación, del que no te has dado cuenta. Dices "objetos empleados para representar información a través de notación hexadecimal", pero estos objetos no _representan_ información en notación hexadecimal. Trabajan con datos **binarios** que es una manera de decir _con bloques de memoria sin importar lo que contengan_. De allí sus nombres. `bytearray` por ejemplo, es un _arreglo de bytes_.

Comment: Por conveniencia, esta información suele _convertirse_ a una representación hexadecimal, por ejemplo al querer mostrar el contenido de la memoria, ya que un byte puede representarse con solo dos dígitos hexadecimales, ocupa menos espacio que hacerlo en decimal u octal, donde ocuparía tres, y no digamos en binario, dónde ocuparía ocho. Pero, nada impide hacer este tipo de representaciones.

Comment: De igual manera, si estás asignando valor a un byte del arreglo, puedes _darle_ ese byte a python en representación hexadecimal (`0xFF`), o decimal (`255`), pero también podrías hacerlo en octal (`0o377`) o en binario (`0b11111111`), aunque estas son menos populares, están igualmente soportadas.

Comment: @jachguate bueno eso ya lo sabia (el hecho de que los objetos binarios son basicamente para representar informacion sin un tipo especifico, simplemente bytes que posteriormente se interpretan como se desee y que por convencion se emplea el sistema hexadecimal para ocupar menos espacio), unicamente que no lo comente, no lo considere relevante para la pregunta. Sin embargo no sabia que los objetos binarios tuviesen soporte directo para otro tipo de representacion aparte de la hexadecimal, gracias por eso :)

Comment: Este soporte de las diferentes notaciones no es _de los objetos binarios_, sino del lenguaje. Igual puedes asignarle un valor así a un entero, solo por dar un ejemplo sencillo `mientero = 0b0110101010101010`.